# Laravel is trying to find my public files in wrong directory when I use parameter in restful url

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to load a page using this laravel route:

```
Route::get('products/{category}', "ProductsController@index");
```

In the controller I return an oridnary view using blade and a master page. The problem is that the view can't load it's resources because it is trying to find them in a folder named "products".

```
localhost:8000/products/<and it is searching for the images and styles here instead the public folder>
```

do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How do you load your resources?

Comment: with "images/filename.png", they are in my public folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you are not using *absolute URLs* to load your resources. You are probably doing something like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

What this will do is, that it will try to load the resource by appending `css/style.css` to the current URL.

**For example:**

If you are at: `http://localhost/pages/home` then, it may look for the resources at `http://localhost/pages/css/style.css`

**Therefore the fix:**

Use absolute URLs.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/style.css">`

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: It looks like in Laravel 4 and 5 we should use {{ URL::asset("image_path") }} to be able to use the public files... when I use it it pastes "http:// localhost...." and will work when  I upload my website to a host.

Comment: Just pass a variable to blade.php as `url` which contains the value of your URL.

Comment: So that you can do `{{ $url }}/css/style.css`